# How to create an invoice in odoo via odoo-xmlrpc in node?

Tags: node.js, odoo, xml-rpc, invoice

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/odoo-xmlrpc to create invoices in odoo 10. I can create an invoice, but i am unable to add invoice line_items to the invoice.

```
//connect to odoo
var odoo = new Odoo({
  url: "xxx",
  port: 443,
  db: "xxx",
  username: 'apiuser123456',
  password: 'xxx'
});


odoo.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  console.log('Connected to Odoo server.');
  var inParams = [];
  inParams.push({
    'partner_id': 119,
    'account_id': 162,
    'invoice_line': [(0, '', { 'account_id': 162, 'name': "AAA", 'quantity': parseFloat('3'), 'price_unit': parseFloat('5') })]
  });
  var params = [];
  params.push(inParams);
  odoo.execute_kw('account.invoice', 'create', params, function (err2, value2) {
    if (err2) { return console.log(err2); }

  });
});
```

this code actually creates an invoice in odoo, but it does not add any line. I assume that the invoice_line attribute is somehow wrong but I fail to find the problem. I would have expected to see one line in the invoice with a total amount of 15 Eur.

Comment: I think the correct field name is `invoice_line_ids` instead of `invoice_line`

Comment: changing to invoice_line_ids results in an error on execution. XML_RPC fault - KeyError: 0 , so i would assume that this means the key is not found which would point in the direction that invoice_line is correct

Comment: From [odoo source code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py#L323), you can see the correct field name is `invoice_line_ids`, no reference to `invoice_line` in the model. The "KeyError: 0" seems to indicate Odoo was not able to interpret the value you passed. I think there is no tuple type in JS. maybe the value `(0, '', { 'account_id': 162, [...]})` doesn't make sense...

Comment: Maybe try with `[0, '', { 'account_id': 162, ...}]` (brackets instead of braces)

Comment: 'invoice_line_ids': [[0, '', { 'account_id': 162, 'name': "AAA", 'quantity': parseFloat('3'), 'price_unit': parseFloat('5') }],[0, '', { 'account_id': 162, 'name': "AAA", 'quantity': parseFloat('3'), 'price_unit': parseFloat('5') }]]  - this one works, so i guess i need to use a 0 to indicate that the line needs to be created first.

Comment: Yes. `invoice_line_ids` field is a One2many, the first brace corrspond to "a list of lines". The second one build a special "command" (a triplet) describing how the line must be interpreted. (0, _, values_dict) means "add a new invoice line using `values_dict`. See https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.write for more info

Comment: got that now, hwoever facing issues now adding tax to line items. Apparently this does not work [[0,"",{"account_id":162,"name":"Product abc","quantity":1,"price_unit":17,"invoice_line_tax_ids":[[12]]}]] following the same logic. invoice_line_tax_ids is a many2many field, any hints on how to handle this? @Antwane the id 12 corresponds to a tax is in my instance. The order is created properly but without any tax. Thanks a lot !

Comment: "invoice_line_tax_ids":[12] (only 1 pair of braces)

Comment: [[0,"",{"account_id":162,"name":"Prodcut abc","quantity":1,"price_unit":17,"invoice_line_tax_ids":[12]}] does not work though. No error, but no tax either. What am i missing?

Comment: Some Odoo libraies doesn't support passing directly a list of id to set a one2many or a many2many value. Try this: `[[0,"",{"account_id":162,"name":"Basic Tarif August 2019","quantity":1,"price_unit":17,"invoice_line_tax_ids":[6, 0, [12]]}]`

Comment: does not work either. I defined a product with the tax set in the masterdata. but even when using this product in the invoice line it does not set the tax. Unlike when I add the product via the Odoo UI, where the tax is set correctly. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/odoo-xmlrpc it does not explicitly mentions the many2many support but since it worked for the one2many case for invoices_lines i would have assumed it workd for many2many as well. what do the first two parameters stand for ```[6, 0, [12]]```

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.write

Comment: thanks, should have found that myself, sorry. This looks pretty straight forward then, but still i cannot get any tax in the invoice line, could it be that I have to manually trigger an event after creating the invoice to have the tax calculation triggered or something like this?

Comment: I can't help you, I have a pretty similar issue creating invoices via API, and didn't find any clue to solve it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is how i solved it:

1- adding the invoice_line_tax_ids as lined out above:

```
invoiceLines = [
  { 'account_id': 162, 'name': "Product A", 'quantity': 1, 'price_unit': 17, 'product_id': 1 },
  { 'product_id': 1, 'account_id': 162, 'name': "Product B", 'quantity': 1, 'price_unit': 17 }
]

-------------------
// partnerId is an id of an existing partner in odoo

function createInvoiceObj(partnerId, lineEntries) {

  inParams = [];
  params = [];
  inParams.push({
    'partner_id': partnerId,
    'account_id': 162,
    'invoice_line_ids': lineEntries
  });  
  params.push(inParams);
  odoo.execute_kw('account.invoice', 'create', params, function (err, invoiceId) {
    if (err) { throws('error during execution createInvoiceObj() ' + err); }
    return createTax(invoiceId);
  });
}
```

2- create tax entries for each line (find lineIds for invoice first)

```
function createTax(invoiceId) {
  var inParams = [];  
  var params = [];
  inParams.push([['invoice_id', '=', invoiceId]]);
  params.push(inParams);
  odoo.execute_kw('account.invoice.line', 'search', params, function (err, invoiceLineIds) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    invoiceLineId = invoiceLineIds[0];

    inParams = [];
    inParams.push(invoiceLineIds);
    inParams.push({ 'invoice_line_tax_ids': [[6, 0, [12]]] })
    params = [];
    params.push(inParams);

    odoo.execute_kw('account.invoice.line', 'write', params, function (err, value) {
      if (err) { return console.log('Error during execution ' + err); }
      return compute_taxes(invoiceId)
    });


  });
}
```

3- trigger tax calculation on invoice

```
function compute_taxes(invoiceId) {
    inParams = [];
    params = [];
    inParams.push(invoiceId);
    params.push(inParams);

    odoo.execute_kw('account.invoice', 'compute_taxes', params, function (err, result) {
      if (err) { return console.log(err); }  
      return invoice_open(invoiceId)
    });

  }
```

so the magix fix at the end was to call the compute_taxes function. However, i tried to take the next step and automatically confirm the invoice, but this still fails. I used  the invoice_open workflow, but this shows no result:

```
function invoice_open(invoiceId) {

  var params = [];
  params.push(invoiceId);

  odoo.exec_workflow('account.invoice', 'invoice_open', params, function (err, value) {
    if (err) { return console.log("Error during execution " + err); }
console.log('Result invoice_open: ' + value); 
  });

}
```

this function always returns `false` but with no error message. The invoice state is not transsitioned to "confirmed" either.

Answer (score 1):

One2many and Many2many fields can be set with the magic triplets or better A LIST of those triplets. Since you're using JavaScript here, i recommend using list triplets -> `[MagicNumber, ID or nothing, List of IDs, nothing or values dictionary]`

So for invoice lines it should be

```
'invoice_line_ids': [[0, 0, {'field1': value1, 'fieldn': valuen}],
                     [0, 0, {'field1': value1, 'fieldn': valuen}]]
```

That will add two completely new created invoice lines.

The same goes for Many2many fields for example taxes on invoice lines

```
'invoice_line_tax_ids': [[6, 0, [12]]]
```

That will add the tax with ID 12 to the many2many relation. Just provide more than one ID to add more to the relation.

Little hint: those magic triplets can be found in the official documentation or directly in the code as docstring on `BaseModel.write()`

Edit: In newer versions Odoo introduced the class `Command` to handle these triplets in a more readably way. The [doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command) describes this as:

> `One2many` and `Many2many` fields expect a special command to manipulate
> the relation they implement.
>
> Internally, each command is a 3-elements tuple where the first element
> is a mandatory integer that identifies the command, the second element
> is either the related record id to apply the command on (commands
> update, delete, unlink and link) either 0 (commands create, clear and
> set), the third element is either the values to write on the record
> (commands create and update) either the new ids list of related
> records (command set), either 0 (commands delete, unlink, link, and
> clear).
>
> Via Python, we encourage developers craft new commands via the various
> functions of this namespace. We also encourage developers to use the
> command identifier constant names when comparing the 1st element of
> existing commands.
>
> Via RPC, it is impossible nor to use the functions nor the command
> constant names. It is required to instead write the literal 3-elements
> tuple where the first element is the integer identifier of the
> command.
>
> CREATE = 0
>
> UPDATE = 1
>
> DELETE = 2
>
> UNLINK = 3
>
> LINK = 4
>
> CLEAR = 5
>
> SET = 6

Comment: thanks very much, this clarified a lot already. I was now able to add the tax ids  and I can see it in the UI as well, that the tax is assigned. However the amounts are not updated as they should. Do i need to trigger this separately or set any further fields as well? I canhardly imagine that i need to manually calculate all amounts and set it manually (would be quite error prone). Thanks again for any hint.

Comment: What is the explanation of the magic "6" that appears there? I first mistook this for 0 and continued debugging for a while. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I've edited new info and a link to the doc.